# Столкновение с повёрнутым спрайтом

Tags: c#, xna

Я делаю игру, в которой шарик должен лететь к повёрнутой платформе и отталкиваться от её поверхности. У меня есть код в методе Update, который отвечает за проверку столкновений:

```
if (ball.Rectangle.Bottom >= platform.Rectangle.Top && ball.Rectangle.Left >= platform.Rectangle.Left && ball.Rectangle.Right <= platform.Rectangle.Right)
{
    ball.SpeedY = -ball.SpeedY;
}
```

И код в методе Draw, который отвечает за отрисовку платформы:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(platform.Texture, platform.Rectangle, null, Color.White, -0.4f, new Vector2(0, 0), SpriteEffects.None, 1);
```

Но если я использую код в методе Update, то шарик отталкивается не от самой поверхности, а чуть ниже неё. Помогите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы шарик отталкивался именно от поверхности?

Comment: а вы это ваше условие обсчитываете до или после того как подвинете шарик в сторону его скорости?

Comment: Условие обсчитывается после того, как шарик двигается.

Comment: ну то есть вам надо на каждом шаге учитывать, попадет ли шарик ниже поверхности если сделает шаг, и если попадет, то уменьшить, чтобы шарик не провалился